# How resilient are fruit fly larvae?

Tags: pest-control

For some reason, this summer, the fruits I got had lost of fruit flies.  It led to an infestation in my apartment, which I got rid of using a cup containing a shallow amount of apple cider vinegar, to which I added a few drops of dish detergent.  I covered the cup in saran wrap in which I poked 3 holes that were more than big enough for a fruit fly to enter through.

Part of the problem is that I don't change the kitchen garbage every day.  It is a 10L garbage can, and it would be very wasteful to change it every day because I generate a neglegible amount of daily waste.  So even though my cider trap kills the existing fruit flies, whenever I lift the garbage lid to throw stuff out, more flies come out.  They eventually get trapped by the cider, but it's annoying.  I've taken to squirting the vinegar into the garbage can whenever I open it.  It seems to keep the problem under control.  In fact, lately, it seems to have eliminated any fruit flies even when lifting the garbage lid.  The vinegar does dry up, so it's probably too hostile an environment for the flies to mature form the larvae stage.

However, I have found larvae around the edge of the garbage can.  It's a good quality can, [SimpleHuman 10L](http://www.thebay.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/thebay/10l-semi-round-can).  They seemed quite inanimate, probably due the the vinegar.  For good measured, I soaked them again, then wiped them up.  Unfortunately, dead-looking larvae also seemed to be in crevices in the garbage can that required vacuuming.  Now, I took the precaution of tossing the vacuum bag, but it was a huge waste because it was largely empty.

So my question is, how likely is it that these dead looking larvae are actually alive but inanimate because of the vinegar trauma, but still have a potential to revive?  What if they are simply very sedentary and not dead?  If they are likely to revive, then I have to throw out an almost empty vacuum bag every time I vacuum up such larvae, which is not only wasteful but expensive for high end vacuums and environmentally criminal.

P.S. Some of the crevices were such that even vacuuming left one or two, and I drenched them in 70% isoproppyl alcohol.  I later read that fruit flies saturate they offspring with alcohol, so that probably wasn't a great idea.

P.P.S. Just a heads up...vinegar is not the greatest thing to spray into a garbage can.  It may be a high end stainless steel can, but the screws will turn into molten pulps of rust.  Isopropyl alcohol is a good alternative.

P.P.P.S. I posted this to [usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/alt.home.repair/k7Xv_Zgc5CU) and [Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100784/how-resilient-are-fruit-fly-larvae).

Comment: FWIW I always thought the vinegar was just there to attract them and what actually kills them is simple drowning...

Comment: I suspect that the apple scent attracts them because I've never seen a solution that uses white vinegar instead of cider. Considering that vinegar is used to disinfect (though not very thoroughly), I hoped that it would harm them. Also, having spent hours over the course of days spray them with vinegar, It seems to put them out of commission. It's not conclusive by any means, though. Perhaps they simply retreat and convalesce in some nook or cranny somewhere. Those that don't escape seem incapacitated, but that might simply be the soaking in moisture, preventing them from flying/walking.

Comment: +1 Because you have a valid question about pest control.  It is just difficult to understand what you are describing.  I don't even think you need to describe the larvae that much.  Just boil it down to: Does a light spray of vinegar kill larvae?  Is alcohol more effective at killing larvae?

Comment: For a while, don't use your big trash can.  Reuse old grocery bags as trash bags and take them out everyday.

Comment: Washing the can out and disinfecting it should kill all the larva. Chunks of leftover food or food residue may be enough protection for them to survive.

Comment: @Zach Mierzejewski: I added a clarification to the end of the 3rd last paragraph.  Thanks for pointing out its necessity.  About your suggestion to use daily grocery bags every day, I'm trying to avoid taking grocery bags (I re-use each one almost forever).  But I will if I have to.  However, could you please elaborate on why that helps?  I *suspect* that it deprives any residual live eggs/larvae of any food.  When they all die off, then I can resume using my normal garbage can, is that the idea?  (That is, until the next batch of fruit with unusually high number of fruit fly eggs).

Comment: @Ed Beal: Agreed that left over food debris sustains the fruit flies.  That's why I tried to vacuum up what I could, sprayed the can with vinegar, and used alcohol to drown the debris and inanimate larvae that evaded vacuuming.  Hence my (now clarified) question of how likely it is that the larvae will revive and breed in the vacuum bag.  It would be wasteful to switch out an almost empty vacuum bag every few days or every week (I did it this time, though).

Comment: I have never used a vacuum to clean a garage can, I use hot water and bleach and they are done.

Comment: The garbage is the main source of food for them.  Also, keep moist food sources in airtight bags and run your sink after you dump something down it. (The sink matters more when you have a large garbage disposal cavity that people don't think about.)  You want to deprive them of food.  **Animals go where the food is.**  They also like to nest in your garbage (obviously) because it's dark and moist and has food.  The **fruit fly** (you may not have actual name brand fruit flies) takes 5 days from the time ...

Comment: the eggs are laid to the time they can fly.  This means if you take out the trash on day 4, all 1000 babies that can't fly yet get thrown out and never get the chance to reproduce in your house.  Now, there are other bugs that reproduce much, much faster so you want to take the trash out every 1 day.  You also want to scrub your trash can with soap and water (Yes!  Just soap and water will do all the work.) because you obviously have food stuck somewhere.  It may not even be "human" food.  They may be feeding on the corpses of their brothers that you've already killed.

Comment: When confronted with any pest, research its life cycle.  Animals do two things: food and sex.  Identify the easiest part of the lifecycle to kill them at.  Killing flying animals is a lot harder than killing an egg.

Comment: Response to Ed & Zach's suggestion to scrub trash can with soap/bleach and water: The plastic bin which I put the garbage into is easy to disinfect. It's the outer can which is hard to clean because the structure is complicated and doesn't actually hold water. It is basically a mechanical unit with some kind of lever system that allows the foot pedal to raise the lid. That's why I ended...

Comment: ...up vacuuming. What couldn't be vacuumed was drowned in alcohol, but that just leaks right onto the floor. I seem to be on top of the problem now with the apple cider trap, the cleaning of the garbage unit, and the spraying vinegar into the garbage. No larvae or fruit flies. If they come back, I'll re-disinfect and temporarily take out the trash daily. Thanks.